# How to join two tables and do mathematical calculations

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

I have two tables, EmployeeDetails and CompOffTable. I want to add rows of CompOff table and the result i get on the count of each row should be added to a column to EmployeeDetails table. I have used Left Out Join. Please Help me with this code.

```
SELECT 
  a.EmpID, 
  a.EmpName, 
  a.Department, 
  a.Designation, 
  a.TotalLeaves, 
COUNT(b.EmpName) AS TotalCompOff                         
FROM (EmployeeDetails a LEFT OUTER JOIN
(CompOffTable b ON a.EmpName = b.EmpName) 
INNER JOIN SUM(a.TotalLeaves + TotalCompOff) AS RemainingLeaves )                        
GROUP BY a.EmpID, a.EmpName, a.Department, a.Designation, a.TotalLeaves
```

Comment: ms-access and mysql are two very different products. Please edit you question to remove the wrong one.

Comment: Edited. How can I improve my query? @ZoharPeled

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Sample data as DDL+DML and desired results should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INNER JOIN SUM(a.TotalLeaves + TotalCompOff) AS RemainingLeaves )
```

You cannot join to that calculation. Assuming the calculation is what you are seeking, try the following which simply moves it back into the select clause. Also note that you cannot refer to the column alias **totalcompoff** in the same select clause. You simply have to repeat the method for arriving at the column **COUNT(b.empname)** instead. This does not make the query any less efficient by the way.

```
SELECT
      a.empid
    , a.empname
    , a.department
    , a.designation
    , a.totalleaves
    , COUNT(b.empname) AS totalcompoff
    , SUM(a.totalleaves + COUNT(b.empname)) AS remainingleaves
FROM employeedetails a
LEFT OUTER JOIN compofftable b ON a.empname = b.empname
GROUP BY
      a.empid
    , a.empname
    , a.department
    , a.designation
    , a.totalleaves
```

If the db type/version does not allow that construct then use a derived table approach, and here you can re-use the column alias:

```
SELECT
      d.empid
    , d.empname
    , d.department
    , d.designation
    , d.totalleaves
    , d.totalcompoff
    , SUM(d.totalleaves + d.totalcompoff) AS remainingleaves
FROM (
      SELECT
            a.empid
          , a.empname
          , a.department
          , a.designation
          , a.totalleaves
          , COUNT(b.empname) AS totalcompoff
      FROM employeedetails a
      LEFT OUTER JOIN compofftable b ON a.empname = b.empname
      GROUP BY
            a.empid
          , a.empname
          , a.department
          , a.designation
          , a.totalleaves
      ) d
```

Comment: Cannot have aggregate function in expression SUM(a.TotalLeaves + COUNT(b.EmpName)) 
error @Used_By_Already

Comment: added alternative method.

Comment: @Used_By_Already: Are you sure about the "alternative method"?  When running this (with MariaDB), I get only one row - see dbfiddle, second-to-last query, and last query.  http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=a3769dc3ad18e938f3c0c68ec7ca05cb

Comment: No Luck :(  The Error now says "You tried to execute a query that does not include specified expression EmpID" @Used_By_Already

Comment: Very clearly **empid** is listed in the query above 3 times in fact. I'm not aware of MySQL being case sensitive but you could try **EmpID** instead.

Comment: No, It wont work even then. I have been trying many things but I'm not getting the proper result. @Used_By_Already

Answer (score 0):

If you data looks like this

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select e.emp_no,e.last_name, e.holiday_entitlement
    -> from employees e;
+--------+-----------+---------------------+
| emp_no | last_name | holiday_entitlement |
+--------+-----------+---------------------+
|      1 | AAA       |                  30 |
|      2 | BBB       |                  30 |
|      3 | CCC       |                  30 |
|      4 | DDD       |                  30 |
|      5 | EEE       |                  30 |
|      6 | FFF       |                  30 |
|      7 | GGG       |                  30 |
+--------+-----------+---------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select id , entity_id , date_from , date_to
    -> from holiday_table;
+------+-----------+------------+------------+
| id   | entity_id | date_from  | date_to    |
+------+-----------+------------+------------+
|    1 |         1 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-01 |
|    2 |         1 | 2017-02-01 | 2017-02-01 |
|    3 |         2 | 2017-01-01 | 2017-01-01 |
+------+-----------+------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then this might do

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select e.emp_no,e.last_name, e.holiday_entitlement
    -> ,ifnull((select sum(datediff(date_to,date_from) + 1) from holiday_table h where h.entity_id = e.emp_no), e.holiday_entitlement) entitlement
    ->    , ifnull(e.holiday_entitlement - (select sum(datediff(date_to,date_from) + 1) from holiday_table h where h.entity_id = e.emp_no),0) LeaveRemaining
    -> from employees e;
+--------+-----------+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
| emp_no | last_name | holiday_entitlement | entitlement | LeaveRemaining |
+--------+-----------+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
|      1 | AAA       |                  30 |           2 |             28 |
|      2 | BBB       |                  30 |           1 |             29 |
|      3 | CCC       |                  30 |          30 |              0 |
|      4 | DDD       |                  30 |          30 |              0 |
|      5 | EEE       |                  30 |          30 |              0 |
|      6 | FFF       |                  30 |          30 |              0 |
|      7 | GGG       |                  30 |          30 |              0 |
+--------+-----------+---------------------+-------------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a proper answer which i found out with your help

```
SELECT
      d.empid
    , d.empname
    , d.department
    , d.designation
    , d.totalleaves
    , d.totalcompoff
    , SUM(d.totalleaves + d.totalcompoff) AS remainingleaves
FROM (
      SELECT
            a.empid
          , a.empname
          , a.department
          , a.designation
          , a.totalleaves
          , COUNT(b.empname) AS totalcompoff
      FROM employeedetails a
      LEFT OUTER JOIN compoff b ON a.empname = b.empname
      GROUP BY
            a.empid
          , a.empname
          , a.department
          , a.designation
          , a.totalleaves
      )  d 
GROUP BY
  d.empid
, d.empname
, d.department
, d.designation
, d.totalleaves
, d.totalcompoff
```

Comment: Yes my fault. forgot I was using SUM() in the outer query. Well done.

Comment: No Problem You gave me like 90% of the answer the rest I just worked it out. Thanks again @Used_By_Already